# Create new list of dictionary from two list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two list of dictionaries and wanted to create new list of dictionary from existing two list of dictionaries. dict1 have all the details about person (pid, pname , pscore, sid) and dict2 have details about person with city (pid, cid, cscore) wanted to create new list of dictionary where pid from dict1 matches pid of dict2 and add pid, pname, pscore, cscore from both list of dictionaries where match happened into list of new_dict. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
   dict1 = [{'pid': [7830351800, 8756822045, 7985031822, 8882181833],
  'pname': ['ABC', 'XYZ', 'QWE', 'MNQ'],
  'pscore': [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8],
  'sid': 8690694}]
```

```
 dict2 = [{'pid': 7830351800, 'cid': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'cscore': [0.8, 0.78, 0.7, 0.45]},
 {'pid': 8756822045, 'cid': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'cscore': [0.9, 0.88, 0.8, 0.75]},
 {'pid': 7985031822, 'cid': [9, 10, 11, 12], 'cscore': [0.5, 0.48, 0.3, 0.25]},
 {'pid': 8882181833, 'cid': [2, 13, 14, 15], 'cscore': [0.6, 0.58, 0.5, 0.45]}]
```

```
   new_dict = [{'pid': 7830351800,
  'pname': 'ABC',
  'pscore': 0.8,
  'cid': [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'cscore': [0.8, 0.78, 0.7, 0.45]},
 {'pid': 8756822045,
  'pname': 'XYZ',
  'pscore': 0.8,
  'cid': [5, 6, 7, 8],
  'cscore': [0.9, 0.88, 0.8, 0.75]},
 {'pid': 7985031822,
  'pname': 'QWE',
  'pscore': 0.8,
  'cid': [9, 10, 11, 12],
  'cscore': [0.5, 0.48, 0.3, 0.25]},
 {'pid': 8882181833,
  'pname': 'MNQ',
  'pscore': 0.8,
  'cid': [2, 13, 14, 15],
  'cscore': [0.6, 0.58, 0.5, 0.45]}]
```

I tried below code but ran into error. I am not able to understand how to solve this. Just started learning python:

```
new_dict = {}
for k, v in dict1[0].items():
    if v[0] in dict2[0]['pid']:
        new_dict = dict({'pid': v[0], 'pname' :v[0], 'pscore':v[0], 'cid':dict2[0]['cid'], 'cscore':dict2[0]['score']})
        print(new_dict)
```

Comment: those are 2 lists...

Comment: @Ironkey yeah my bad list of dictionaries, let me update my question. Thanks

Comment: Also, could you show us what you've already tried? We really don't write code for people here.

Comment: @Ironkey I am very beginner in python i tried solving this but couldn't find a way to do it. got error, Here i am attaching my code  : new_dict = {}
for k, v in dict1[0].items():
    if v[0] in dict2[0]['pid']:
        new_dict = dict({'pid': v[0], 'pname' :v[0], 'pscore':v[0], 'cid':dict2[0]['cid'], 'cscore':dict2[0]['score']})
        print(new_dict)

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: [Edit] additional details into your question, don't add a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
dict1 = dict1[0]

pname_dict = {key:value for key,value in zip(dict1['pid'], dict1['pname'])}
pscore_dict = {key:value for key,value in zip(dict1['pid'], dict1['pscore'])}
ans = dict2.copy()

for d in ans:
    d['pname'] = pname_dict[d['pid']]
    d['pscore'] = pscore_dict[d['pid']]
```

**Output :**

```
>> ans

[{'pid': 7830351800,
  'cid': [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'cscore': [0.8, 0.78, 0.7, 0.45],
  'pname': 'ABC',
  'pscore': 0.8},
 {'pid': 8756822045,
  'cid': [5, 6, 7, 8],
  'cscore': [0.9, 0.88, 0.8, 0.75],
  'pname': 'XYZ',
  'pscore': 0.8},
 {'pid': 7985031822,
  'cid': [9, 10, 11, 12],
  'cscore': [0.5, 0.48, 0.3, 0.25],
  'pname': 'QWE',
  'pscore': 0.8},
 {'pid': 8882181833,
  'cid': [2, 13, 14, 15],
  'cscore': [0.6, 0.58, 0.5, 0.45],
  'pname': 'MNQ',
  'pscore': 0.8}]
```

Create 2 dictionaries to match `pid ->pname` and `pid->pscore`. These dictionaries are used to add the other 2 key values to the `dict2`

Comment: Thank you it helped, simple and clean solution.